# Looking for story about man on televised trial, presents plans for laser gun

Tags: story-identification

I would like to find a story about a man (maybe a farmer/rancher?) on trial for something I thought farm-related, which is live-televised to the world, who presents the plans for a homemade laser- or ray-gun in bits and pieces during the trial. Objections are raised to his information but he prevails and

> by end of story he has given the full plans to the world, and influenced how humanity will continue with any one being the possessor of this deadly technology.

I was convinced this was Bradbury but cannot find it as such. I recall that it was in a collection of scifi short stories; would likely have read it 1978-1985 (but it could have been an older volume that I picked up then). Thanks for any help.

Comment: Now why does this story suddenly sound so topical? >_>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's [Committee of the Whole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Committee_of_the_Whole_%28short_story%29) by Frank Herbert. I think I read it in The Best of Frank Herbert, though I've mislaid my copy so I can't check.

From the article:

> It deals with the concept of restraint as a paramount virtue necessary for survival of a human race in times when both information and the means for production of weapons of mass destruction are available to every individual.

Comment: Thanks so much! Mind is Officially.Blown. by how fast you answered. And the Frank Herbert fan in me is sooo embarrassed.